# Kotlinpoet How to add inner object class definition?

Tags: kotlin, code-generation, kotlinpoet

I am trying to generate an object definition inside of a class. This is a distilled version:

```
class SomeClass {

   // need to figure out how to generate this
   companion object {

      // and this
      object Constants {
         val SOME_CONSTANT = "CONSTANT VALUE"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Change `object` to `companion object`

Comment: I suppose it should be static and therefore inside the `companion object {}`, however, I still would still like to generate the `object Constants` block inside of the companion object. This allows for the namespacing of my constants. Will update code block to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `object` with `TypeSpec.objecBuilder` and then nest it in a class with `addType`, for example:

```
val constants = TypeSpec.objectBuilder("Constants")
        .addProperty(PropertySpec.builder("SOME_CONSTANT", String::class)
                .mutable(false)
                .initializer("CONSTANT VALUE")
                .build())
        .build()

val someClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder("SomeClass")
        .addType(constants)
        .build()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for. Wish some of these nuances were better documented in the kotlinpoet readme. Will most likely make a PR with this example

Comment: Looks like it is actually already in the README, just doesnt have an output example. My bad, should have read more thoroughly.

Comment: The unit tests are also a great place to look, that's where I found something similar to figure this one out.